# php-fpm does not load new code after deployment

Tags: restart, php

I meet a problem with php-fpm when deploying new code to the webserver.

I have nginx + php-fpm + apc  to serve my site. for code deployment, I use git to pull code form git repository.

The problem is : when I git pull the new code to deploy code update to web server, php-fpm does not reflect the update, still serve the code before pull.  I have to restart php-fpm, then the updated code is served.

This is very inconvenient for deployment. I googled around but does not find any hint about the reason behind.

Can anyone tell me why and is their any way to avoid restart?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't actually sound like an FPM problem but an APC related issue. I believe your APC is caching your content and it wouldn't be reflected until FPM was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed does sound like a php-fpm problem. You have to reload php-fpm in order to update what php files are being served. To do this run "service php-fpm reload" or "service php7.0-fpm reload" for php7. This basically clears its code cache and refreshes to display the newest state of your code.